# In flutter_inappwebview not able to share URL through facebook and twitter. Click itself it's not working

Tags: flutter, webview

In my webview am having two buttons to share the URL.Find the attached screenshot.[image: screenshot].

Actually it is working in google chrome and safari and Android devices. It's not working in iOS. Am using flutter_inappwebview(https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview). Actually it will open new window. Am not getting any console error also. When I click on **share on twitter** and **share on facebook** am getting error as this **InAppWebView - dealloc**. May I know if anyone has any idea about this?